# MassTransit how to unit test state machine

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, masstransit, state-machine

I'm having trouble configuring some unit tests for a StateMachine.

I have gone through most of the examples in GitHub as well as in Youtube but I can't figure out why this is not working.

The test case itself is as follows. It's pretty much the same as the one in the [official documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/testing#saga-state-machine).

One thing that I noticed is that if I remove this piece
**"x.InsertOnInitial = true;"** the test succeeds...

```csharp
public class DeleteAccountStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<DeleteAccountSaga>
{
    // [...] States...
    // [...] Events...

    public DeleteAccountStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => InitiateAccountDeletion, x =>
        {
            x.InsertOnInitial = true;

            x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.AccountId);
            x.SetSagaFactory(context => new()
            {
                CorrelationId = context.Message.AccountId
            });
        });
        
        Initially(
            When(InitiateAccountDeletion)
                .TransitionTo(Received)
                .Send(context => new DeleteFilesT1(context.Message.AccountId))
                .Send(context => new DeleteFilesT2(context.Message.AccountId))
                .TransitionTo(DeletingFiles)
        );

        // [...]
    }
}

// The test class
public class StateMachineTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        await using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
            {
                x.AddSagaStateMachine<DeleteAccountStateMachine, DeleteAccountSaga>()
                    .InMemoryRepository();
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);
        
        var testHarness = serviceProvider.GetTestHarness();
        var sagaTestHarness = testHarness.GetSagaStateMachineHarness<DeleteAccountStateMachine, DeleteAccountSaga>();

        await testHarness.Start();

        var command = new InitiateAccountDeletion(Guid.NewGuid());

        await testHarness.Bus.Send(command);

        // Verify that command is consumed by the bus.
        // This is OK.
        Assert.True(await testHarness.Consumed.Any<InitiateAccountDeletion>(
            x => x.Context.Message.AccountId = command.AccountId
        ));

        // Verify that command is consumed by the saga.
        // This is OK.
        Assert.True(await sagaTestHarness.Consumed.Any<InitiateAccountDeletion>(
            x => x.Context.Message.AccountId = command.AccountId
        ));

        // Verify that the saga instance is created.
        // This FAILS. <=============================================================
        Assert.True(await sagaTestHarness.Created.Any(
            x => x.CorrelationId.AccountId = command.AccountId
        ));

        await testHarness.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InsertOnInitial` is rarely needed and was designed for special heavy load scenarios using SQL Server to reduce blocking due to S-RANGE locks. This was more than a decade ago, so I have no real measure of whether or not is adds values.

`SetSagaFactory`, which is only used with `InsertOnInitial`, is also unnecessary.

So I'd remove both of those statements, and then your tests will pass.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now, I'm having trouble with a **CompositeEvent**. The 2 events get consumed by the SM, but it's never transitioned to the next State. Is there any special thing that must be done to test a CompositeEvent? I couldn't find any example of such.

Comment: Unrelated comments are not a place to ask questions on SO.

Comment: I raised a separate question for such. I would be pleased to have an expert's feedback on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266233/masstransit-how-to-unit-test-compositeevent-in-state-machine