# MassTransit how to unit test CompositeEvent in state machine

Tags: masstransit

I'm having trouble testing a StateMachine that has a CompositeEvent.

All messages are being consumed by the saga. Furthermore, the FilesState has a value of 3, meaning that the CompositeEvent has been completed.

For some reason, the saga remains in DeletingFiles state.

```csharp
public class DeleteAccountStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<DeleteAccountSaga>
{
    // [...] States...
    // [...] Events...

    public DeleteAccountStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => InitiateAccountDeletion, x =>
        {
            x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.AccountId));
        });
        
        Initially(
            When(InitiateAccountDeletion)
                .Send(context => new DeleteFilesT1(context.Message.AccountId))
                .Send(context => new DeleteFilesT2(context.Message.AccountId))
                .TransitionTo(DeletingFiles)
        );

        CompositeEvent(() => FilesDeleted, x => x.FilesState,
            FilesT1Deleted,
            FilesT2Deleted
        );

        During(DeletingFiles,
            When(FilesDeleted)
                .TransitionTo(FileDeletionComplete)
        );

        // [...]
    }
}

// The test class
public class StateMachineTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        await using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
            {
                x.AddSagaStateMachine<DeleteAccountStateMachine, DeleteAccountSaga>();
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);
        
        var testHarness = serviceProvider.GetTestHarness();
        var sagaTestHarness = testHarness.GetSagaStateMachineHarness<DeleteAccountStateMachine, DeleteAccountSaga>();

        await testHarness.Start();

        var command = new InitiateAccountDeletion(Guid.NewGuid());

        await testHarness.Bus.Send(command);
        await testHarness.Bus.Publish(new FilesT1Deleted(command.AccountId));
        await testHarness.Bus.Publish(new FilesT2Deleted(command.AccountId));

        // This FAILS. <=============================================================
        Assert.True(await sagaTestHarness.Exists(message.AccountId, x => x.FileDeletionComplete));

        await testHarness.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably wait until the messages are consumed to account for message ordering:

```cs
public class StateMachineTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        await using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
            {
                x.AddSagaStateMachine<DeleteAccountStateMachine, DeleteAccountSaga>();
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);
        
        var testHarness = serviceProvider.GetTestHarness();
        var sagaTestHarness = testHarness.GetSagaStateMachineHarness<DeleteAccountStateMachine, DeleteAccountSaga>();

        await testHarness.Start();

        var command = new InitiateAccountDeletion(Guid.NewGuid());

        await testHarness.Bus.Publish(command);

        // wait until the message is consumed, it's asynchronous
        Assert.True(await testHarness.Consumed.Any<InitiateAccountDeletion>());

        await testHarness.Bus.Publish(new FilesT1Deleted(command.AccountId));
        await testHarness.Bus.Publish(new FilesT2Deleted(command.AccountId));

        Assert.True(await sagaTestHarness.Exists(message.AccountId, x => x.FileDeletionComplete));

        await testHarness.Stop();
    }
}
```